# created an spring mvc project using maven in eclipse , only index.jsp loads rest requests goto to error 404

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" id="WebApp_ID"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee;
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>

      <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>




Servlet-context.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.pack" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />



    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

control.java

```
package org.pack;



import org.springframework.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class control {


    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(Model m){
        m.addAttribute("name", "Ashu");
    return "welcome";
    }


}
```

this is the directory structure , when i run application using wildfly 10 only default index.jsp loads and no other controller loads , error is 404 and the request does not reach the controller

Answer (score 0):

Component scan base package, in `servlet-context.xml`, is `org.pack`; but your controller class is in `org.test` package. Then the controller class wont be scanned for `@Controller` annotation. Change base package in xml to `org.test` and post the result on comment.

Also edit this `<beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/" />` to `<beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />`

Comment: yeah i had corrected that earlier , still no luck http://imgur.com/a/nXABH

Comment: is there anyway that i can know whether my dispatcher servlet is loading and redirecting to the correct url

Comment: Use a logging mechanism like log4j and enable debugging in log4j.properties.

Comment: log4j still does'nt show whether dispatcher servlet is redirecting request or not

Answer (score 0):

`<context:component-scan base-package="org.pack" />` will only register the beans in `org.pack` package and your controller class in present in package `org.test`.

Either change package name to `org.pack` in controller or change `<context:component-scan base-package="org.pack" />` to `<context:component-scan base-package="org" />`

Comment: Corrected : <context:component-scan base-package="org.pack" /> will only register the beans in "org.pack" package and your controller class in present in package "org.test". Either change package name to "org.pack" in controller or change <context:component-scan base-package="org.pack" /> to <context:component-scan base-package="org" />.

Comment: yes i had already corrected that , i figure the problem is that dispatcher servlet is not redirecting

Answer (score 0):

Try to put sysout in controller method and check if request is reaching to controller or not. Also post screenshot of your directory structure.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/lkFCY , i feel dispatcher servlet is not working properly as i had already put logging in java's controller file

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/SOhlB it just goes to the predefined index.jsp file and after any hitting any other url it shows 404

Comment: why are you putting java packages inside src/main/resources? they must be in src/main/java. and your log4j.properties should be in src/main/resources. Also try to remove index.jsp and check if it works

Comment: I can see the views folder is in WEB-INF folder. so prefix must be  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" /> instead of <beans:property name="prefix" value="/views/" />

Comment: Move your java packages into src/main/java not in src/test/java

Answer (score 0):

Current structure will not work in your case as you are adding all `class` resources i.e. your `controller` and more in incorrect `source` folders as per your provided https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahamr.jpg

It shows that your `java` classes are in `src/main/resource`.

Instead please move those to `src/main/java`.

`src/main/resource` is generally used for any sort of configuration files, like log4j , resource bundle files etc.

Also, you need to then update the `component-scan` package path to discover your beans like `Controller` etc

Do build, deploy on widlfly and try once again!.